# Find height lines of the function $e^{x^2+y}$

Tags: calculus, functions

Find height lines of the function $e^{x^2+y}$. Well, I'm not sure it's called "height lines", but here's the solution: (see picture below)

My question: How do I find those height lines? In other words, how do I find $y$? I know it's really simple but I couldn't manange to understand why the equation is $e^{x^2+y} = h$ and then they just put $ln$ in LHS and RHS and they get $y$. Is that how I do with every function? I just make it equal to $h$ and find $y$?

[image]

Comment: They are called Contour Lines. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you can use the notion of "Level curves".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contour lines are the set of points that gives the same result. We know them from meteorology. By the definition, if you have a 2 dimensional function $f(x,y) = z$, then a contour line for $z = c_n$ is the set of $(x,y)$ points where $f(x,y) = c_n$.

Now for example find the set of contour line for $z = 1$. We need to find $(x,y)$'s s.t. $e^{x^2 + y} = 1$. That is $x^2 + y = ln(1) = 0 \implies y = -x^2$.

Another contour line, for example, for $z = 4$ can be find by the equation $y = ln(4) - x^2$.

But sometimes you may have nice functions where you can not pull $y$ or $x$ and write them in closed form against each other.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, these curves are contour lines corresponding to $$e^{x^2+y}=h$$ where $h$ is a given constant; so $$y=-x^2+\log(h)$$ In the graph you produced, the $y$ intercept corresponds to $\log(h)$.